# Can we create a label for a variable in SAS remote session?

Tags: sas

Could anyone please resolve my query.

I have to create a label for few variables in a sas dataset. I am using the below code to do that.

```
    rsubmit;
data cls;
set sashelp.class;
run;

proc datasets ;
modify cls;
label age ='Age of student';
quit;
enrsubmit;
```

But it not creating the label for the age variable.
Please suggest a resolution or workaround for this.

Thanks,
Teja

Comment: What do you get in the log from the PROC DATASETS? How do you know it's not labeled, did you run PROC CONTENTS inside of the submit block?

Comment: **340  modify cls;
341  label age ='werser';
342  quit;

NOTE: MODIFY was successful for WORK.CLS.DATA.
NOTE: PROCEDURE DATASETS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds**

I am getting above log when i ran proc datasets. I checked in data set properties and column properties. label was not updated.

Comment: are you sure you are looking at your _remote_ work library?

Comment: Looks like a happy log. I would add `PROC contents data=cls; run;` inside your resubmit block.

Comment: Yes, I am looking in the remote work library.

Comment: @Quentin I have ran the proc contents in remote session and checked, but the labels were not updated

Comment: If the log is clean and the PROC contents does not show the label as updated, I would send your code into tech support, and see if they can replicate it.  Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: He likely has the option nolabel set for some reason.